# Remove duplicate items from list if certain properties match and get the top item based on some ordering

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of Objects lets say User.

```
public class User
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Sex {get;set;}
public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}
public string Type {get;set;}
public string SubType {get;set;}
public int FilterId {get;set;}
}
```

Lets say I have the following results

```
Josh, M, 5/1/1980, Admin, Main, null
John, M, 5/1/1980, User, Main, null
Jane, F, 5/2/1980, User, Main, null
Josh, M, 5/1/1980, Admin, Main 1
John, M, 5/1/1980, User, Main, null
Josh, M, 5/1/1980, User, Main, null
```

I would like to get the following results back.

```
Josh, M, 5/1/1980, Admin, Main 1
John, M, 5/1/1980, User, Main, null
Jane, F, 5/2/1980, User, Main, null
Josh, M, 5/1/1980, User, Main, null
```

The important part is that it returns the record of Josh for where FilterId is not null.  I thought something like a Group By with an Order By and firstordefault.

I am having trouble writing the groupby clause with multiple fields in it and getting that to work properly.

Modified the example to reflect the additional properties that need to be part of the groupby.

Comment: "I thought something like a Group By with an Order By and firstordefault."  Great.  That does sound like a promising idea.  What implementations did you come up with *using* that idea?  Show us what they are and explain why (specifically) they are not working.

Comment: OK, so did you put the thought into code? How did it work out?

Comment: Sorry I should have provided more details.  I am having a hard time writing the GroupBy() clause for this.

Comment: @Josh The group by is easy.  That part is simply `.GroupBy(user => user.Name)`.  That's all.  From there you need to project each group into a single item using your given criteria.

Comment: @Servy I added the additional groupby columns to more accurately represent my needs.  I really need a group by on Name, Type, and SubType.

Comment: @Josh This is why it's important to include such information in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'FilterId' can never be null since it's an `int`. Assuming its actually an `int?` aka `Nullable<int>`, this will work:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = GetSomeUsers() ;
User[] distinctUsers = users
                       .GroupBy( x => new Tuple<string,string,DateTime>(x.Name,x.Sex,x.Birthday))
                       .SelectMany( g => g.OrderBy( x=> x.FilterId.HasValue ? 0 : 1 )
                                          .ThenBy( x => x.FilterId )
                                          .Take(1)
                       )
                       .ToArray()
                            ;
```

This code

- groups on name, gender and birthdate
- orders each group on filter id such that non-null values collate first, followed by null values
- takes the first element of each group (there is always at least one element in a group).
- flattens it into a single list
- turns it into an array.

Answer (score 1):

the groupby part:

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name , x.Sex, x.Birthday});
```

and from here just pick the first:

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name , x.Sex, x.Birthday}).Select(y=>x.First());
```

if you want the first one to be without null you can do OrderByDescending

```
.OrderByDescending(usr=>usr.FilterId ).GroupBy(x => new { x.Name , x.Sex, x.Birthday}).Select(y=>y.First()).ToList();
```

filterId is an integer. it can't be null

Comment: This won't work.  Your group by will be grouping based on the identify of the `User` objects, not based on their values, unless you provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<User>` that defines value equality for that type.

Comment: @Servy fixed and tested it

Comment: You changed one of the three solutions.  Two are still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to group on multiple properties is to use an anonymous type:

```
var groups = users.GroupBy(user => new
    {
        Name,
        Type,
        SubType,
    });
```

This works because the implementation of anonymous types is such that they override the `Equals` method to compare the values of each member of the type, and also overrides the `GetHashCode` method to make it a composite hash of the hashes of all of the values of the object.  If you just created a new named type you would need to handle all of that yourself, which is simply tedious.

Answer (score -1):

The main understanding is to use the IEqualityComparer, the class LambdaCustomComparer is a helper to do that using LINQ dynamically.

You need copy and Paste this :

---

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int? FilterId { get; set; }
}

public class LambdaCustomComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer;
    private readonly Func<T, int> lambdaHash;

    public LambdaCustomComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer, bool ignoreHashcode = true)
    {
        if (lambdaComparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaComparer");

        this.lambdaComparer = lambdaComparer;
        if (ignoreHashcode)
            lambdaHash = obj => 0;
        else
            lambdaHash = EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode;
    }

    public LambdaCustomComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer, Func<T, int> lambdaHash)
    {
        if (lambdaComparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaComparer");
        if (lambdaHash == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lambdaHash");

        this.lambdaComparer = lambdaComparer;
        this.lambdaHash = lambdaHash;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return lambdaComparer(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return lambdaHash(obj);
    }
}

var list = new List<User>
{
    new User() {Name = "Josh", Sex= "M", Birthday = DateTime.Now, FilterId = null},
    new User() {Name = "John", Sex= "M", Birthday = DateTime.Now, FilterId = null},
    new User() {Name = "Jane", Sex= "F", Birthday = DateTime.Now, FilterId = null},
    new User() {Name = "Josh", Sex= "M", Birthday = DateTime.Now, FilterId = 1},
    new User() {Name = "John", Sex= "M", Birthday = DateTime.Now, FilterId = null},
};

var comparer = new LambdaCustomComparer<User>((a, b) => a.Name == b.Name && a.Birthday.Date == b.Birthday.Date && a.Sex == b.Sex && a.FilterId == b.FilterId);

var distinctList = list.GroupBy(user => user, comparer).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.ToArray());
```

Comment: This is not properly hashing values for these types (it's just using the default implementation, which is not going to use value semantics), and as a result `GroupBy` won't work.

Comment: It won't work because it'll use the default `GetHashCode` implementation of `User`, which doesn't override the implementation of `object`, which bases the hash on the object's reference, whereas your goal here is to have a hash code based on several of the values within that object.

Comment: I understood your viewpoint, congratulation. Maybe isn't the best way, but it works.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the solution, Santin ? It would help @Josh and others reading your answer.